# C Variadic Function not working as intended

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I'm trying to make a function that takes a string with format (like printf, but instead of "%i" I want it to be "n" (for learning purposes, don't ask me why)). Here is the function:

```
void test(char* args, ...)
{
    int length = strlen(args);
    va_list list;
    va_start(list, length);

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if (args[i] == 'n')
        {
            printf("%i", va_arg(list, int));
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I call it like this: test("n", 13); it gives another number (-858993460). What's the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Curious: Which compiler and which C library did you use?

Comment: @mafso I use visual studio. What do you mean by library, (like stdarg.h)?

Comment: I mean the C standard library (with which `stdarg.h` and most other standard headers is usually shipped), under Windows, that's probably MSCRT (iirc). Visual Studio is not a compiler, but an IDE (using MSVC as the compiler by default). Gcc ignores the second argument of `va_start`, I was wondering how the mistake in the code could result in an error (it's right to fix it, even with Gcc, of course) and how your compiler handles `va_start`. Anyway, thanks for the reply, now I know where to look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call `va_start` like this:

```
va_start(list, args);
```

The second parameter of `va_start` must be the name of the last parameter of `test` before the ellipsis, which is `args`.

Comment: Do you know how you can take a function pointer as variadic argument?